# Intro Java - How does the use of char work? letter assigned by random number?

Tags: java, char

I am completely perplexed by this char scenario. 
I understand that in java if you using a single character you use char. I understand math.random but I have no idea how the random number is assigned a uppercase letter?

The way I read this is: 
print -> type case char primitive type -> the letter "A" -> concatenate a random number up to 27...

but this code works How?

```
public class question {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println((char)('A' + Math.random() * 27));
  }
}
```

Comment: The character `'A'` is just a human representation. It's actually just a binary number in the underlying system. Java considers it an integer and can therefore perform arithmetic on it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I never knew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert an `int` to a `char`, the integer value is used as the index of the character in the [ASCII](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange) table.  So this code uses the ASCII code of an uppercase A (65) and adds 0 to 25 to it to get an character from `A` to `Z`.

As @ruakh said in the comments, you should add values in the range `[0, 25]` to `A` to get the characters from `A` to `Z`.  Therefore use `Math.random() * 26` instead of `Math.random() * 27`.

Comment: Your answer contains a fencepost error. (Or rather: the original code contains a fencepost error, which your answer preserves.)

Comment: Wow I just looked up asciitable.com and learned something completely new!

Comment: Oh, sorry for linking to the German Wikipedia. Was a matter of habit. ;)

Comment: ------------------ ;) Danke

Answer (score 2):

In Java, a `char` is essentially a 16-bit unsigned integer as well as a single symbol. When using + between a char and integer, instead of concatenation, you use normal addition. Each character's value is their usual unicode value: capital A is 65.

So what's happening here? Math.random() produces a random floating point number in the range [0..1). That is multiplied with 27 (order of operations) and the result is added to 65. Finally, the resulting number is cast to char and printed, resulting in a random letter of the alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` can be treated as an integer for a number of purposes -- e.g. `A` is 65 (in ASCII and Unicode). When you add that to a random number between 0 and 25 and casting it back to `char`, you're generating a random letter between A and Z. Simple!

Comment: Your answer contains a fencepost error. (Or rather: the original code contains a fencepost error, which your answer preserves.)

Comment: Ha, I thought it did.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class question {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println('A' + 1); //The result is 66.
    System.out.println('B' + 1); //The result is 67.
    System.out.println('C' + 1); //The result is 68.
    System.out.println('A' + 100); //The result is 165.
  }
}
```